# Storing bitmap image in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bitmapimage

I need to store the bitmap image information in an XAML-formatted file. Can anyone please help me out on this regard?

Comment: Do you mean you want the binary data itself to appear in the XAML? That will be pretty inefficient even if it's possible, as it'll have to be base 64 encoded. Normally you'd refer to a resource in an assembly, or a file.

Answer (score 3):

[It can't be done](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/08/230443.html) (Charles Petzold)

> Sure, you can refer to external
>   bitmaps in XAML files, but you can't
>   embed a bitmap in a XAML file. What
>   you would need is a class that derives
>   from BitmapSource that has a property
>   named Data or something that you could
>   set to an array of bytes, and a
>   converter that would accept a list of
>   quoted bytes in the XAML file. And
>   such a class does not exist.
>
> What you really shouldn't be doing is
>   getting weird and dangerous ideas,
>   like possibly simulating a bitmap
>   using a UniformGrid containing a bunch
>   of one-pixel square Rectangle objects,
>   one for each pixel. That's just nuts.
>
> Once you start thinking crazy thoughts
>   like that, you're likely to take a 6K
>   220×260 color JPEG and convert it into
>   a [1.9 megabyte EmbeddedBitmap.xaml](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/08/EmbeddedBitmap.xaml)
>   file that takes way too much time to
>   load and compose.
>
> Surely you have better sense than
>   that!

Comment: hello Shay Erlichmen, what I need is, I want to store image information into xaml format. and I want to know how do i do the same using c# code. pls help me out on this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be a valid request for some few cases, like embedding small button images in png format.
I have not tried it, but I think the following is valid:

- Embedd a string into your xaml code containing a base-64 encoded
  image
- Instantiate a converter, that will take a bas-64 string and
  return an Image
- Place an Image object into the xaml, bound to the
  base-64 string and using the mentioned converter

By the way, I have seen that case (small icons) embedded in HTML pages, where it is possible without a converter.